# I am getting an error after importing pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

i just installed pytest and i tried using it and it was giving me errors. i uninstalled it and installed it again and it was giving me the same errors as i tried importing it

```
import pytest


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytest\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 26, in <module>
    import py
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from py._vendored_packages import apipkg
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py\_vendored_packages\apipkg\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .version import version as __version__
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

can you please help me with what to do, or suggest another library just like pytest where i test my applications.

Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

1. check if you installed pytest in the same pyenv you are using. Run `pip list` comand and check there is pytest there
2. It might be issue with environment in pyenv. Try to create new one. In PyCharm it is **File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> Add**

Comment: Pytest is in the list of apps when i run pip list.